# List-Style CSS override back to default

Tags: css

I want to turn this css element back to the default setting and I can't figure out how to override these list-style css elements.  They are on another style sheet that I can't alter but I'm linking to. Please help if you know how.

```
ol li {
  list-style: decimal;
}
ol {
  list-style: decimal outside;
}
```

Comment: I mean the default according to how the browser understands OL and Li

Comment: https://drafts.csswg.org/css2/#html-stylesheet

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use `!important`, e.g.:

```
ol li {
  list-style: inherit !important;
}

ol {
  list-style: inherit !important;
}
```

Comment: I would only use !important as a last resort. It negates specificity, which can have unintended consequences, and makes maintenance a nightmare. It's not technically wrong, but it's not a best practice.

Comment: I'll upvote this if you clarify that `!important` should only be used in cases like this, where you have a stylesheet you can't change, but you have to override it.

Comment: That's not actually the case. Consider: `button:active { color: red; } button:first-child { color: blue; }`. I want all active buttons' text to be red but the first button's text should be normally blue. The two selectors have the same specificity, and only the rule order tentatively determines the outcome (which is awful.) In this case I'd put `button:active { color: red !important; }` to avoid selector bloat, since I know the :active state is really most important in this situation. http://jsfiddle.net/ygcYG/

Comment: You need to use  a selector with minimum specificity that is still stronger. For example, `.my-module ol li { ... }` should win

Answer (score 5):

It's not advisable to use !important, ever really. You can do what chipcullen said above by adding a container or if you want a simple override that will work no matter what, you can do something like this:

```
body ol {
  margin: 1em 0;
  padding: 0 0 0 40px;
}

body ol li {
  list-style-type: decimal;
}
```

The values I put inside there should reset to the browser defaults, and are taken from [normalize.css](https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css).

Answer (score 2):

You may need:

```
ol li { display: list-item; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go about trying to use specificity to set the li styling to whatever you want. Do you have a parent element that you could hook onto? Like, if it was a div with the class container, do something like:

```
.container ol li {
  /* whatever you want */
 }
```